# String difference in java

Tags: java

**Why String class is immutable in Java, as everytime we call certain methods on a
    String reference variable , new String is created?**

```
  public class Test {

       public static void main(String [] args) {

            String s = "abc";
            s.toUpperCase(); // new String is created here.
            System.out.println(s);// prints abc instead of ABC
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked an answer :)

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195099/why-is-string-immutable-in-java
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/190699/when-and-why-would-we-use-immutable-pointers/190913#190913

Comment: Read the documentation for String.  `toUpperCase` *returns* a new String -- the original is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

> Why String class is immutable in Java, as everytime we call certain methods on a String reference variable , new String is created?

No. It's not because of creating new String. Go in reverse. Why each time time you are getting a new String ?

String backed by an char array which is final inside String class. So once you create a String, the char array  never altered after the String object creation. That is the actual reason behind it.

Answer (score 1):

There are types in java, whose instances are immutable. except for `String`, there are `BigInteger, BigDecimal` and `Integer, Long, Double, Float, Short, Byte .(those wrapper types)..` even `Boolean` Those instances are immutable.  If you do something changes on those instance, those instance's self won't be changed.

E.g.

```
Long num = 7L;
num = num + 10L;
```

after you run those two lines, the num would be 17, naturally. But after you ran the 2nd line, the `num` would be a new `Long` instance. Same as `String`

another example:

```
Boolean b = true;
b = false;
```

the `b` in 1st and 2nd lines are different instances too.

Immutable objects are relatively easier to design, implement and use. I *guess* that's why java applied the immutable design.